# Database design on structure of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a table structured like below. The attribute column here is showing 3 distinct values as an example but in the real world, it has 90 distinct values.

```
+----------+----------+--------------+---------+
| project  | company  |  attribute   |  value  |
+----------+----------+--------------+---------+
| lpa      | new_west | revenue      |   32333 |
| lpa      | new_west | distribution | 3545323 |
| Puma     | Puma     | revenue      |   64645 |
| GridPuma | Puma     | assets_val   |   46455 |
+----------+----------+--------------+---------+
```

The way to uniquely identify records in this table is using `project`, `company`, `attribute`. Is the above structure a better structure in terms of scalability, extensibility etc or is the approach below better?

```
+---------+----------+---------+--------------+------------+
| project | company  | revenue | distribution | assets_val |
+---------+----------+---------+--------------+------------+
| lpa     | new_west |   32333 | 3545323      | NULL       |
| Puma    | Puma     |   64645 | NULL         | 46455      |
+---------+----------+---------+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: The first model is called Entity-Attribute-Value, and is widely discouraged except in certain instances. Do the attributes being used vary widely between different `project, company` pair, are they likely to change at runtime?

Comment: @Charlieface They do not vary and are unlikely to change. Can you elaborate on why it is discouraged. I have been trying to explain this to the business people for a while.

Comment: Think of attributes having different value types .. about references and referencial integrity.. That's why  you'd better stick with the second structure till it's absolutely impossible.

Comment: Just search for "EAV". A good starting point is this [software engineering post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios). Note how old it is - many of the "space" issues have better solutions in current versions of sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if this is how you should store the data or are you asking about a structure for say a temp table to do some calculations or reporting?

I would only 'store' data in normalized tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 90 distinct values today, then you could have 91 tomorrow.

For that reason, storing the values in separate rows seems like a better choice -- it is much simpler to add a new row to a table than a new column.

In addition, you can store other information such as the date/time that a value was inserted.